# Normalize SVGs icons and web fonts

Tags: css, svg, gruntjs, npm

I have a bunch of icons in SVG format that were delivered to me by my graphics designer. These icons will used in a app and a website. When using them on the website, I thought of optimizing them converting them into web fonts. Since I was already using grunt, I decided to use grunt webfont plugin. It converted everything to a web font which I can call easily and size using the 'font-size' attribute. 
However, I'm running into several issues now:

1. It seems like the baseline for all icons is not the same. Some appear much above the regular base line while some go below. See the screenshot below:
   [image]
2. In certain cases, when using the fonts they seem add extra space below the element which disturbs the spacing. This seems related to the line-height/font-size property. If I make the font size smaller, the extra spacing disappear, however, the font icons are almost invisible in that case. I worked around the issue by using overflow:hidden on the parent container: [image]
3. Lastly, certain icons appear lighter/smaller compared to other icons which appear quite bold.

Upon investigation, I found the issue - the source SVG files were of different sizes. Some even had enclosing white box or white space around the graphic as shown here.

Give then above, is there a way I can:

1. Normalize all the files to be of the same size without editing the source SVG (using Illustrator or Inkscape for instance)
2. Make sure all the icons have the same baseline
3. Remove the white/empty boxes around the icons from the SVG files.

Can the above be achieved without editing the source file using a plugin or do I have to go and edit each file individually?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know grunt but maybe [the svg-sprite plugin](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite) is what you're looking for.

Or, you could make a [batch process in illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html#play_an_action_on_a_batch_of_files) for it. I assume that a similar option is available in Inkscape.

Below is an example of an action that you can use in Illustrator CC, for points 1 and 2. Save it into `myActions.aia` and then import it in `Illustrator`>`Actions`window>`▸`options panel>`Load Actions...`.

```js
/version 3
/name [ 12
 416c69676e2b726573697a65
]
/isOpen 1
/actionCount 1
/action-1 {
 /name [ 10
  616c69676e2b53697a65
 ]
 /keyIndex 0
 /colorIndex 0
 /isOpen 1
 /eventCount 3
 /event-1 {
  /useRulersIn1stQuadrant 0
  /internalName (adobe_selectAll)
  /localizedName [ 10
   53656c65637420416c6c
  ]
  /isOpen 0
  /isOn 1
  /hasDialog 0
  /parameterCount 0
 }
 /event-2 {
  /useRulersIn1stQuadrant 0
  /internalName (ai_plugin_alignPalette)
  /localizedName [ 9
   416c69676e6d656e74
  ]
  /isOpen 0
  /isOn 1
  /hasDialog 0
  /parameterCount 1
  /parameter-1 {
   /key 1954115685
   /showInPalette 4294967295
   /type (enumerated)
   /name [ 21
    566572746963616c20416c69676e20426f74746f6d
   ]
   /value 6
  }
 }
 /event-3 {
  /useRulersIn1stQuadrant 0
  /internalName (adobe_commandManager)
  /localizedName [ 16
   416363657373204d656e75204974656d
  ]
  /isOpen 0
  /isOn 1
  /hasDialog 0
  /parameterCount 3
  /parameter-1 {
   /key 1769238125
   /showInPalette 4294967295
   /type (ustring)
   /value [ 30
    46697420417274626f61726420746f20617274776f726b20626f756e6473
   ]
  }
  /parameter-2 {
   /key 1818455661
   /showInPalette 4294967295
   /type (ustring)
   /value [ 21
    46697420746f20417274776f726b20426f756e6473
   ]
  }
  /parameter-3 {
   /key 1668114788
   /showInPalette 4294967295
   /type (integer)
   /value 2164261256
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: @thedorkknight Didi this helped ? I assume, thanks to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087803/grunt-cwd-option-issue) that you had some try with `svg-sprite`